# New Activity for different orientation Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, orientation, landscape-portrait

I know that I can create a folder called layout-land in my res/ folder and Android will handle this automatically. My problem is what if I want to call a new Activity when my orientation changes from portait to landscape?

What I have:

- An xml file for portrait that consists of a button and a scrollview
- An xml file for landscape that contains multiple buttons, textviews,
  and edittexts
- Both are called main.xml (but in their respective folders)
- One Activity that calls setContentView(main.xml)

This activity however has to initialize all the buttons, textviews, etc, but when I change the orientation back to portrait, it force closes because those buttons are not in that xml file!

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` to check the current orienation. 
So you can avoid inflating the wrong ressources when u tilt your device.

-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Another (but bad!) approach could be to override `onConfigurationChanged`, so your land-layout won't be used and you can push another activity when tilting. Its like:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //push new activity via intent
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend this for you. Give the first approach a try and tell me wether this worked for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's solution should work, but also know that if the buttons that are common to both portrait and landscape mode do the same thing, you could simply check if findViewByID(...) is null before trying to cast it/assign it. From the documentation of findViewByID(...) `The view if found or null otherwise.` Something like this should work:

```
Object x = findViewByID(R.id.something) != null;
if(x != null)
{
    //cast it to whatever it really is (textview, button, etc)

    //Add whatever listeners you want
}
```

Mind you, I would still go with Thomas's solution because then you only have to check one property, as opposed to having to check for null on each of the controls that differ between layouts.